# Postgres HA standby not using certificate

Tags: postgresql, high-availability

Using Postgresql 11.2 for a warm standby setup.  The issue is we are required to use certificates as part of our authentication process. If I comment out the ssl/certificate lines from standbys postgresql.conf I get the same error.  So I do not believe standby is using the certificates I specify to create the connection to master.  How do I tell Postgresql what certificates to use for outgoing replication connections?

Master pg_hba.conf:

```
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
local     all             all                                    md5
host      all             all                   127.0.0.1/32     md5
host      all             user                  fe80::/10        md5
host      all             all                   ::1/128          md5
hostssl   all             user                  ::/0             cert map=cert
hostssl   all             user                  0.0.0.0/0        cert map=cert
hostssl   replication     user                  ::/0             cert map=cert
hostssl   replication     user                  0.0.0.0/0        cert map=cert
```

Master pg_ident.conf:

```
cert /^(.*)$ user
```

Master postgresql.conf:

```
bytea_output = hex
standard_conforming_strings = on
wal_level = replica
archive_mode  = on
max_wal_senders = 5
wal_keep_segments = 32
listen_addresses = '*'
listen_addresses = '*'
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = '/opt/server/config/Server-signed.crt'
ssl_key_file = '/opt/server/config/Server.key'
ssl_ca_file = '/opt/server/config/master.crt'
```

Standby recovery.conf:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=example.url.com port=5432 user=user password=NoTThePassword sslmode=require'
restore_command = 'cp /opt/pgsql/data/archive/%f %p'
archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup /opt/pgsql/data/archive %r'
```

Standby postgresql.conf:

```
bytea_output = hex
standard_conforming_strings = on
wal_level = replica
archive_mode  = on
max_wal_senders = 5
wal_keep_segments = 32
listen_addresses = '*'
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = '/opt/server/config/7/client-7-signed.crt'
ssl_key_file = '/opt/server/config/7/client-7.key'
ssl_ca_file = '/opt/server/config/7/master.crt'
```

Master output:

```
2019-11-15 12:23:15.784 CST [28044] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-11-15 12:23:21.650 CST [28068] FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
2019-11-15 12:23:21.670 CST [28069] FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
```

Standby Output:

```
2019-11-15 12:23:21.630 CST [7571] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2019-11-15 12:23:21.644 CST [7577] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
cp: cannot stat ‘/opt/pgsql/data/archive/000000010000000000000001’: No such file or directory
2019-11-15 12:23:21.664 CST [7579] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
```

Note: I edited logs/config files to remove sensitive paths/urls/usernames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set those values in primary_conninfo in Standbys recovery.conf.

Mine looks like this now:

```
primary_conninfo = 'host=example.url.com port=5432 user=user password=NoTThePassword sslmode=require sslcert=/opt/server/config/7/client-7-signed.crt sslkey=/opt/server/config/7/client-7.key sslrootcert=/opt/server/config/7/master.crt'
```

All the values that can go in primary_conninfo are documented here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING

Answer (score 1):

The certs you specified in the standby's postgresql.conf are for use with connections the standby *receives*, not for connections it *makes*.

When the standby is acting as a [client](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html) to connect to the master, it uses what it finds in `~/.postgresql/` or `%APPDATA%\postgresql\`, unless you override those settings in the connect string (like Brinnis suggests) or by the environment variables.  Of course '~' here refers to the home directory of the user who is running the PostgreSQL standby server, which will usually be the user named 'postgres'.